# How to handle data from nested dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

Im have setup a nested Dictionary as follows:

```
static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<UInt32, TClassType> > m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<UInt32, TClassType>>();
```

The "TClassType" contains three attributes:

- Title    (string)
- code     (uint)
- Address  (string)

I add value to this nested structure as follows:

```
TClassType newEntry = new TClassType(s_title, ui_code, s_address)
if (! m_dictionary.ContainsKey(s_title))// check as the same s_title can occur multiple times but have different ui_code and s_address values
{
    m_dictionary.Add(s_title, new Dictionary<uint, TClassType>());
}
m_dictionary[s_title].Add(ui_code, s_address);
```

Now my question is what is a good way to access all of the values for a specific key [s_title]?

the key [s_title] will contain many items within the nested Dictionary, and for a unique [s_title] entry I would like to obtain all of the relevant keys and values related to this outter key from within the nested Dictionary.

Sorry I hope that's not confusing, I find it as hard to ask as I do trying to implement.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "a good way to access"? What's the usage context?

Comment: First of all, your example is mixing things up. You are checking if key `s_title` exists, then you add an entry with key `s_type`. Please fix / clearify. And where does `s_key` come from?

Comment: So you try to build an Index for your TClassType first grouped by title, then by code?

Comment: Thanks for the changes. Now please modify your text. In your question you are refering to `s_type` and  `s_key` which never occur in your example code.

Comment: Sorry but I hope its a little more accurate now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (m_dictionary.Contains(s_title))
    foreach(TClassType entry in m_dictionary[s_title].Values)
        // Do something with the entry.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used linq before? This would be a prime usage for groupby. What you're doing adds a level of convolution.

With your current setup if you have a list of TClassType you would be able to use the linq where expression to grab only those with the title you are looking for and then the ui_code you need.

Edit for example (I was on mobile before which is hard to code on :))

```
IEnumerable<TClassType> entries = entriesList;//whatever you use to populate the entries
var titles = entries.Where(x=> x.s_title == "Title you're looking for").Distinct();
```

Comment: I havnt yet but I just investigated, looks very useful :) Thank you

Comment: When I give answers to people I try to give answers within the scope of their question, and probably within the scope of their knowledge. Of course LINQ could help out, but offering new techniques could make the situation more complex and might not even give the desired result (for example: LINQ could decrease performance).

Comment: That may be true and others are doing that, but to not give alternatives limits the potential knowledge base. I know personally I enjoy being presented with other options because I learn more, yes it can obfuscate the initial problem, but learning other techniques gives additional toolsets. As you said, Linq can slow things down, but so can a nested dictionary of large size.